# Pipe() doesn't work well - linux

Tags: c, linux, pipe

I'm trying to make a program using the pipe communication. This is what I'm trying to do: the user sends positive integers. If the user sends a negative number the communication ends. The parent process prints the maximum number and the minimum number. This is what I tried:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
int pfd[2];
int buff[200];
pipe(pfd);
if(fork()==0){
   close(pfd[0]);
   int n;
   printf("Give a number: ");
   scanf("%d",&n);
   while(n >=0 ){
      write(pfd[1],&n,1);
      printf("Give a number: ");
      scanf("%d",&n);
   }
  exit(0);
  }
else{
  close(pfd[1]);
  read(pfd[0],buff,sizeof(buff));
  printf("The parent read %d:",*buff);
  wait(0);
}
}
```

This `printf("The parent read %d:",*buff);` prints only the first number I gave. Can someone explain to me better what I have to do? How to print all the **buffer**? Am I writing only 1 number in the buffer and that's it? How do I find the **maximum** and the **minimum** number? I am very confused! :(

Comment: You need to call `fflush(NULL)`... and you could use `fdopen` (or perhaps `popen`)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Where? What does fflush does?

Comment: For correctness/portability, that write call should be `write(pfd[1], &n, sizeof(n))`.  It won't change the behavior you see, however.

Comment: `What does fflush does?` - type: man fflush   and press enter in your linux terminal and you can see what it does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a way to do what I think you're trying to do with a very few modifications.
Notice that `buff` is no longer an array and that we use the pipe itself as temporary storage as we print the numbers.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int pfd[2];
    int buff;
    int max,min;

    pipe(pfd);
    if(fork()==0){
        close(pfd[0]);
        int n;
        printf("Give a number: ");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        while(n >=0 ){
            write(pfd[1],&n,sizeof(n));
            printf("Give a number: ");
            scanf("%d",&n);
        }
        exit(0);
    }
    else {
        close(pfd[1]);
        printf("The parent read ");

        if (read(pfd[0],&buff,sizeof(int))) {
            max = buff;
            min = buff;
            printf("%d",buff);
        }


        while (read(pfd[0],&buff,sizeof(int))) {
            if (buff > max)
            max = buff;
            else if (buff < min)
            min = buff;
            printf("%d:",buff);
        }

        printf("\n");

        printf("The maximum value is: %d.\n The minimum value is: %d.\n",max,min);
        wait(NULL);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out with the while loop. How do I find the minimum and the maximum number entered after the communication is over(I give a negative number to stop it?

Comment: That's another question... I'm pretty sure the answer is here, on StackOverflow. I guess you could have a maximum and a minimum value, both initialized to the first value you read, and then, in the loop, you can update them each time you read another number (if it's greater than the maximum, you update the maximum, if it's lower than the minimum, you update the minimum).

Answer (score 1):

It might be because `*buff` is a single integer, but you wrote more than one.

If you want to print all integers sent, then you need to know how many was transfered, and then print them in a loop.

---

You also have a problem because you only send *one* byte of the integer (which is normally four bytes). You should use e.g.

```
write(pfd[1], &n, sizeof(n));
```

Comment: @MoldovanRazvan Yes because `buff` is an array, while you want to print a single integer. You need to print in a loop, as I state in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you don't understand that `<stdio.h>` functions (like `scanf` and `fprintf`) are different of raw I/O syscalls like [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) and `write(2)` (actually `printf` and `fprintf` can call `write(2)` and you may force them to do that with `fflush`)

I don't understand what is the protocol you are wanting on the pipe. It seems that you want to send raw bytes (then you are restricted to 0-255). Or do you want to send each number in ASCII, one per line?

Perhaps you could do (assuming the protocol is textual, numbers in ASCII, one per line) in the parent process

```
 FILE* wp = fdopen(pfd[1],"w");
 if (!wp) { perror("fdopen wp"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
 int num = -1;
 do {
    num = 0;
    printf("Enter a number:\n");
    fflush(NULL);
    if (scanf(" %d", &num)<=0) break;
    fprintf (wp, "%d\n", num);
 } while (num>=0 && !feof(stdin));
 fclose(wp);
```

and in the child process

```
 FILE* rp = fdopen(pfd[0], "r");
 if (!rp) { perror("fdopen rp"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
 while (!feof(rp)) {
   int rnum = -1;
   fflush(NULL);
   if (fscanf(" %d", &rnum)<=0) break;
   printf ("parent has read %d\n", rnum);
 };
```

If you want to use only low-level I/O syscalls (i.e. `read(2)` and `write(2)`) you have to manage buffering by yourself (so, take into account the result of `read` and `write` syscalls, which may be a partial count of bytes read or written).

Don't forget to compile with `gcc -Wall -g` (all warnings and debugging information) and learn to use `gdb` for debugging.

Comment: This is why.  If you want to send the number 1, you need to send 4 bytes.  So instead of write(array[0], &n, 1), it should read be write(array[0], &n, 4).  on the other side of the pipe, you need to read 4 bytes into an int, and then you can get the correct number.  If you send ascii, you'll want to use an unsigned char, then only send 1 byte when you call write.  On the other side, you cast to a char, and then you'll have your ascii number.  You also need to know how much to read or else you won't know when to stop reading and you will block waiting for information from the pipe.

Comment: It should at least be `write(pdf[1],&n,sizeof(n))` and you should *check* the number of bytes written (returned by `write`).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
    int pfd[2];
    int buff[200];
    pipe(pfd);
    if(fork()==0){
        close(pfd[0]);
        int n;
        printf("Give a number: ");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        while(n >=0 ){
            printf("Give a number: ");
            scanf("%d",&n);
            write(pfd[1],&n,sizeof(int));
        }
        exit(0);
    }
    else{
        close(pfd[1]);
        /*      loop ??*/
        read(pfd[0],buff,199);
        printf("The parent read %d:",buff);
        /*      loop ??*/
        wait(NULL);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the point in converting to string? You can write anything in a pipe, it functions at byte level.

Comment: Yes, it does. From `write(2)`: `ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);`. It takes a pointer to `void*`, which means it doesn't even look at the content of the buffer. It just prints the bytes, one after another.

Comment: If you update your answer, please do it in a consistent way. `atoi()` is not necessary ;-). It's even undesirable, as `buff` is a array of int.

Comment: And be careful, as `write` takes a pointer. You should write `write(pfd[1],&n,sizeof(int))` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
write(pfd[1],&n,1);
```

only writes one byte.  You need this:

```
write(pfd[1],&n, sizeof n);
```

This reads whatever is available in the pipe buffer

```
read(pfd[0],buff,sizeof(buff));
```

It blocks until there is something to read and then returns however many bytes it actually has read.  The likely sequence is:

```
child writes your first number (probably 4 bytes)
parent reads the first number
parent executes the wait() sys call
you type in the second number (assume its negative)
child writes the second number
child exits
parent exits
```

Your parent needs to keep reading until it has all the numbers it expects or end of file is reached (signified by read returning 0).  Something like this:

```
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = read(pfd[0], buff, sizeof buff)) > 0)
{
    // Do whatever it is you want to do with the bytes
}
if (bytesRead == -1)
{
    // report the error
}
```

Note that, theoretically, you might not even read all four bytes of the int in one go, although, I think, in practice with pipes, this won't happen.