# named pipes(fifo) program doesn't work

Tags: c, linux, pipe, fifo

guys! I am trying to make my first program that uses named pipes or fifo. The client sends to server positive integers. When a negative number is sent, the transmission closes. The server determines the minimum number sent, the maximum number and sends the two values back to the client. The trouble I have is that always the printed max and min are zero and I really don't know how to solve the problem. This is what I have so far:

client.c

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
  int f1,f2;
  int n,a,b;
  printf("Give the number: ");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  while(n >= 0){
    printf("Give the number: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
  }
  f1=open("fifo1",O_WRONLY);
  f2=open("fifo2",O_RDONLY);
  if(f1<0){
    printf("You can't write in the fifo client");
  }
  if(f2<0){
  printf("You can't read from the fifo client");
  }
  write(f1,&n,sizeof(int));
  read(f2,&a,sizeof(int));
  read(f2,&b,sizeof(int));
  printf("The minimum number is %d\n",a);
  printf("The maximum number is %d\n",b);
  close(f2);
  close(f1);
}
```

server.c

```
#include <sys/stat.h> 
#include <fcntl.h>   
#include <stdio.h>

int minim=0;
int maxim=0;

int min(int n){
if(n>=0 && minim > n){
minim=n;
}
return minim;
}

int max(int n){
if (n > maxim){
maxim=n;
}
return maxim;
}


main(){
  int f1,f2,a,b,n;
  f1=open("fifo1",O_RDONLY);
  f2=open("fifo2",O_WRONLY);
  if(f1<0){
    printf("error");
  }
  if(f2<0){
    printf("error");
  }
  read(f1,&n,sizeof(int));
  a = min(n);
  b = max(n);
  write(f2,&a,sizeof(int));
  write(f2,&b,sizeof(int));
  close(f1);
  close(f2);
}
```

Comment: Are you in the same class as, or are you the same person as, the person who asked [this very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16482874)?

Comment: @pilcrow Yes, I am the same person but I forgot the password from that account. :( But how is this relevant for my question?

Comment: And I find strange the tone of the question: actually, named pipes do work as documented, you just have trouble to find out how to use them correctly. It is not the named pipes' fault (or the kernel's fault).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Can you help me solve the problem? I tried over and over again but I didn't fine the solution

Comment: Did you do a `mkfifo` before?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Of course I did. I made mkfifo fifo1 and mkfifo fifo2 because the program is bidirectional

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty simple solution.

For 1, you need to make the fifo with mkfifo.  Idk if you did that before in a seperate program or the file already exists, but without that you won't get anything.

For 2, there's no gaurentee that when you're reading on the server that the file has been written to.  If the client runs first, then you need to flush your write call in order to ensure that the fifo was written to first.  This can be done with fsync().  Once you fsync() on that file descriptor, the file will be written to, and you can gaurentee the values will be there for the server to read.  Verify this by having the server read the fifo and then output what it reads.

Comment: I did make fifo1 and a fifo2, both with mkfifo. So, everything I did is working? I don't understand where I need to use fsync(). Can you tell me exactly where?

Comment: After each write call.  when you write to a file descriptor, it doesn't actually write to the file on the hard drive, it writes it to a special buffer in the linux kernel.  If you were to write with yoru program, and pull the plug on your computer, the changes would not be reflected in the file.  After each write, put fsync(fd) and then pull the plug after the fsync and you'll see that the file has been written to because you flushed it.  DO IT AFTER EVERY WRITE TO MAKE SURE ITS THERE (or do it after the last write).

Comment: Also, there's no guarantee that you're writing to the file before the server reads to it.  How are you ensuring that the timing is synced correctly?

Comment: After the write in client.c I put fsync(f1) and after every write in server.c I put fsync(f2) and the program doesn't work. The printed maximum and minimum are both zero.

Comment: Its because there's a race condition between client and server.  If you take a look at how ls | grep works, which pipes ls to grep using fifo, ls is executed first, then grep.  It doesn't happen all at once.  What you need is your server to block read on the fifo, and then read it after getting a notify update.  Also, read starts at the current file offset, so when you write 1 and 2 from the client, the server starts reading after the 2 (which is EOF).  You need to seek back to the beginning or close the pipe on the client before reading and opening in the server.